Policy regarding blocking bots, self-identified and others
I hope this is OK here. I realize it's more of a discussion-type question.
I'm curious what policy people have with respect to allowing bots on your website. And does it make a difference if it identifies itself as a bot?
I detect and block bots that

Make too many requests
Make calls to non-existent pages. They'll try pages like example.com/admin.php
Make calls with wrong parameters. I might see sql or password or other weird stuff

I don't block verified main search engines. (Except Facebook, which has gone berserk with the number of calls.)
I identify a lot of other bot IP addresses. I can identify these because each call is a new session. A single IP address will typically send many different user agent headers.
Do you block bots that stay within your robots.txt limits, but don't identify themselves as bots? Does it make a difference it is identifies itself as a bot in the user agent?
Do you think there are unidentified bots that might be helpful to you? Maybe you want services to get a sense of your pages or backlinks?
